# Reachability Count for all nodes in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, graph

So there was this challenge on a programming contest on Hackerrank called "Acyclic Graph", which basically boils down to counting the number of nodes reachable from every node in a "Directed Acyclic Graph". For example, say you have a graph like so:

```
[ 1 ] ---->[ 2 ]--->[ 4 ]--->[ 5 ]
[ 3 ] ------/
```

Reachability count (including origin node):

```
Node 1: 4
Node 2: 3
Node 3: 4
Node 4: 2
Node 5: 1
```

My approach was a "Depth First" traversal with memoization. Looked around quite a bit, but it seems as though the run time can't be improved much further because of the over counting that occurs in cases like so:

```
[ 1 ] ---->[ 2 ]--->[ 4 ]--->[ 5 ]
[ 3 ] ------/--------/
```

The third node would count the fourth node, even though the second node already counted the fourth node. To make things a bit worse, I only solve these challenges in JavaScript. Its my primary language and I get a thrill from pushing its boundaries. No one on the leader board has solved it in JavaScript yet, but I presume it's possible. After the contest, I managed to pass 13 out of 24 test cases with the following code:

```
function Solution( graph, nodes ) {

    var memory = new Array( nodes + 1 )
      , result = 0;

    graph.forEach( ( a, v ) => DepthFirstSearch( graph, v, memory ) );

    // challenge asks for an output variation, but the accurate 
    // reachability count of every node will be contained in "d.length".
    memory.forEach( ( d, i ) => { if ( i && ( 2 * d.length ) >= nodes ) result++; } );

    return result;
}

function DepthFirstSearch( graph, v, memory ) {

    if ( memory[ v ] ) return memory[ v ];

    var descendants = new Uint16Array( [ v ] );

    graph[ v ].forEach( u => {

        descendants = MergeTypedArrays( 
            DepthFirstSearch( graph, u, memory ),  
            descendants
        );
    } );
                                           // make elements unique
                                           // to avoid over counting
    return memory[ v ] = Uint16Array.from( new Set( descendants ) ); 
}

function MergeTypedArrays(a, b) {

    var c = new a.constructor( a.length + b.length );

    c.set( a );
    c.set( b, a.length );

    return c;
}

// adjacency list
var graph = [ 
    [],    // 0
    [ 2 ], // 1
    [ 4 ], // 2
    [ 2 ], // 3
    [ 5 ], // 4
    []     // 5
];

var nodes = 5;

Solution( graph, nodes );
```

It fails for all inputs greater than 50kb, presumably inputs with a large set of nodes and edges (i.e. 50,000 nodes and 40,000 edges). Failing to identify or conceive a faster, more memory efficient algorithm, I'm at a total loss as to what to try next. Thought about making the DFS iterative, but I'm thinking the memory consumption of memoizing thousands of arrays will dwarf that, which seems to be the main problem. I get "Abort Called" and "Runtime Error" on Hackerrank for the 11 tests that fail (as oppose to "Timeout"). Also tried "bitSets" with "union", but the memory consumption turned out to be worse since the bitSets arrays need to be large enough to store numbers up to 50,000.

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ n,m ≤ 5×10^4
1 ≤ a(i),b(i) ≤ n and a(i) ≠ b(i)
It is guaranteed that graph G does not contain cycles.
```

Just want to make it clear that I won't get any points for passing all tests since this challenge is locked, this is for educational purposes, mainly on optimization. I'm aware of related SO posts that point to topological sort, but as far as I understand, topological sort will still over count on cases like the one described above, thus not a viable solution. If I misunderstood, please enlighten me. Thank you in advance for your time.

Question: How can I optimize this further? Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: Do you have more information about the test cases e.g. what time/memory contraints they have? To be honest, 50k nodes 40k edges is a tiny graph and even a bad implementation should not have problems with that.

Comment: @MartinS Yes, JavaScript max execution time is 10 seconds and max memory is 512mb. I just ran your versions locally; the recursive one errors on a stack overflow and the iterative one takes ~13 minutes for [this](http://marceli.no/r-files/hackerrank-acyclic-graph/input11.txt) test case (the very first digit is the number of nodes, the digit next to it is the number of edges, the lines below those two digits are the actual edges). Success rate for challenge is 7.87%. I think there is a bit more to it than we realize. I keep going back to memoization since it's doing a lot of repeated work.

Comment: What are `a and b` in these contraints `1 ≤ n,m ≤ 5×10^4`
`1 ≤ a(i),b(i) ≤ n and a(i) ≠ b(i)` ?

Comment: @MartinS Sorry for not specifying that, "a" and "b" refer to the edges. To remove any more ambiguity, [here](http://marceli.no/r-files/hackerrank-acyclic-graph/description.png) is a screenshot of the challenge's description.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depth-First Search (DFS) is one good way of solving this problem. Another way would be Breadth-First Search (BFS) which can also run in parallel and can be optimized very well - but all at the cost of much higher code complexity. So my recommendation would be to stick to DFS.

First I have to apologize, but my JavaScript skills are not very good (i.e. they are non existent) so my solutions below are using Java but the ideas should be easy to port.

Your initial question is missing one very important detail: We only need to find all nodes where the number of reachable nodes is larger or equal than `|V| / 2`

Why does that matter? Computing the number of reachable nodes for each node is expensive as we have to do a DFS or BFS starting from every node in the graph. But if we only need to find nodes with the above property, that is much easier.

Let *successors(n)* be all nodes reachable from *n* and *ancestor(n)* be all nodes that can reach *n*.
We can use the following observations to drastically reduce the search space:

- if the number of nodes reachable from *n* is smaller than *|V| / 2* then no node in *successors(n)* can have a larger number
- if the number of nodes reachable from *n* is greater or equal than *|V| / 2* then all nodes in *ancestors(n)* will have a larger number

How can we use that?

1. When creating your graph, also create the transposed graph. That means when storing an edge a->b, you store b->a in the transposed graph.
2. Create an array that stores which nodes to ignore, initialize it with `false`
3. Implement a DFS based function that determines whether a given node has a number of reachable nodes `>= |V| / 2` (see below)
4. In that function, ignore nodes that are marked as ignored
5. If for node *n* the number of nodes is smaller than *|V| / 2*, mark all nodes in *successors(n)* as ignored
6. Else count all nodes in *ancestors(n)* and mark them as ignored

**Solution using Iterative DFS**

```
public int countReachable(int root, boolean[] visited, boolean[] ignored, Graph graph) {
    if (ignored[root]) {
        return 0;
    }

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(root);

    int count = 0;
    while (stack.empty() == false) {
        int node = stack.pop();
        if (visited[node] == false) {
            count++;
            visited[node] = true;
            for (int neighbor : graph.getNeighbors(node)) {
                if (visited[neighbor] == false) {
                    stack.push(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (count * 2 >= graph.numNodes()) {
        return markAndCountAncestors(root, visited, ignored, graph);
    } else {
        return markSuccessors(root, visited, ignored, graph);
    }
}
```

**Function to mark the Ancestors**

This is just another DFS but using the transposed graph. Note that we can reuse the `visited` array as all values that we will use are `false` since this is an acyclic graph.

```
public int markAndCountAncestors(int root, boolean[] visited, boolean[] ignored, Graph graph) {   
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(root);
    visited[root] = false;

    int count = 0;
    while (stack.empty() == false) {
        int node = stack.pop();
        if (visited[node] == false && ignored[node] == false) {
            count++;
            visited[node] = true;
            ignored[node] = true;
            for (int neighbor : graph.transposed.getNeighbors(node)) {
                if (visited[neighbor] == false && ignored[node] == false) {
                    stack.push(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Function to mark the Successors**

Note that we already have the successors since they are just the nodes where we set `visited` to true.

```
public int markSuccessors(int root, boolean[] visited, boolean[] ignored, Graph graph) {
    for(int node = 0; node < graph.numNodes(); node++) {
        if (visited[node)) {
            ignored[node] = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Function to compute the result**

```
public void solve(Graph graph) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[graph.numNodes()];
    boolean[] ignored = new boolean[graph.numNodes()];
    for (int node = 0; node < graph.numNodes(); node++) {
        Arrays.fill(visited, false); // reset visited array
        count += countReachable(node, visited, ignored, graph);
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + count);
}
```

On the large test-case you posted, this runs in 7.5 seconds for me. If you invert the iteration order (i.e. in `solve` you start with the largest node id) it goes down to 4 seconds, but that somewhat feels like cheating ^^

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, Martins. Your approach was actually what I tried first, my original code looks almost identical. It didn't workout too great. It's actually slower (for two test cases) than the code I presented and errors out passing only 13 cases (passes same test cases as my algorithm, can't handle bigger input). I only moved to the approach I presented in an attempt to cache. I think your iterative code might have some logic errors in it. I couldn't make it work out for other test cases without modifications, it over counts for circular cases. Either way, I appreciate it.

Comment: @marcbraulio I just saw that you have to move the `count++;` after the check whether you have visited the node already - sorry about that.

Comment: No worries :) and you also have to change `visited[node] = false;` to `visited[node] = true;`. Without that change it'll still pass the test case I presented, but it won't pass circular cases. Checkout [this](http://marceli.no/r-files/hackerrank-acyclic-graph/input02.txt) test case and you'll see what I'm saying (the very first digit is the number of nodes, the digit next to it is the number of edges, the lines below those two digits are the actual edges). It should output `Node 1: 3, Node 2: 4, Node 3: 2, Node 4: 7, Node 5: 6, Node 6: 8, Node 7: 10, Node 8: 5, Node 9: 1, Node 10: 9`

Comment: @marcbraulio I used the correct code but somehow posted it wrong here ^^ I updated my answer because it would be too long for a comment

Comment: Not a problem, I appreciate it. So you're telling me that your iterative DFS in Java ran [this](http://marceli.no/r-files/hackerrank-acyclic-graph/input11.txt) test case in 2ms? Based on benchmarks I've done with the infamous "N-Queens" problem, JavaScript (Node.js - V8) is only about three times slower than C. And yes, I'm using what I believe to be an "Adjacency List" to represent my graph (depicted in the my code above). I read it's one of the most efficient graph data structures, do you recommend another way?

Comment: Oh no it runs in 2ms for the test case you mentioned (input02.txt) for the larger one (input11.txt) it takes 10 seconds. But with the additional informationed about the question I got an idea how to improve this. Will need some time to test that though ^^

Comment: Sorry, meant to reply earlier. Before your suggestion to optimize on `>= |V| / 2`, I managed to reduce "input11.txt" from ~13m to ~300s. After the `>= |V| / 2` optimization, I got it down to ~99s. The "input02.txt" was never an issue, it consistently ran 9ms on any version. Inverted iteration did nothing for me and I suspect that it is test case independent. Got access to the [editorial](http://marceli.no/r-files/hackerrank-acyclic-graph/editorial.png) (and author [code](http://marceli.no/r-files/hackerrank-acyclic-graph/e-code.txt)), doesn't seem like they cared for the `>= |V| / 2`.

Comment: All the challenges (200+) I've solved so far had a JS solution that took no more than 2s, not sure if your 4s-7s solution would pass all test cases (time limit for Java is only 4s), but if you give me the Java function to parse the graph edges, I can submit it and let you know. Chat might be best at this point. Thank you for the attention, man. I'm marking your answer as correct since it is in fact more optimal than mine.

Comment: @marcbraulio I made some small optimizations and got the time down to 2.5 seconds. The problem is that it uses proprietary code for loading and representing the graph so I cannot share it with you. But I can implement that by hand when I have some time ^^

Comment: Nice and no worries. What do you think about the approach in the editorial? Changing `visited[neighbor] == false && ignored[node] == false` to `visited[neighbor] == false && ignored[neighbor] == false`, chopped off some time for me.

Comment: Did you come up with this algorithm yourself, or is it sourced from a book or article?

Comment: DFS is a well know algorithm from graph theory, but the code I wrote myself