# Count number of reachable nodes in Directed Graph from each node, faster than O(V^2)?

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, cycle, directed-graph

So I have a Directed Graph which may contain cycles. I need, for each node, to count the number of nodes reachable from this node, and store this in a table. The naive approach would be to use DFS from each node, resulting in at most O(V^2) complexity, which is too slow.

Solving this problem would be easy if there were no cycles, using this algorithm:

```
array numReachable(V elements of -1)

dfs(u):
    if (numReachable[u] != -1) return numReachable[u]
    mark u as VISITED
    count = 1
    for each node v adjacent to u:
        if (v is UNVISITED):
            count += dfs(v)
    mark u as UNVISITED
    return numReachable[u] = count

for each node u:
    dfs(u)
```

However, cycles break it. I've tried workarounds but nothing seems to work. What do I do?

Comment: Maybe I miss something but isn't the `VISITED` mark should avoid cycles? Can you please provide simple example of graph with cycle that breaks the algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count all reachable nodes in a directed graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389163/how-to-count-all-reachable-nodes-in-a-directed-graph)